# How to Change Hub Header Like MSN Food App?(win 8.1)

Tags: c#, xaml

How to Change Hub Header foreground Like MSN Food App?
I tried Hub section GotFocus and LostFocus but it didn't work.

Comment: Hello welcome to StackOverflow. Please post your xaml code so people can see what you have tried

Comment: I just use GotFocus event handler to the second hub section and put a break point to test what happen and I found that the event repeats continuously when the app start.